# Mod rewrite multiple rewrite condtions

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, user-agent

I'm trying this following code to only match if the url contains certain wordpress pages AND either the user agent is blank or matches like (curl/perl/php etc...). However it is doing so even if REQUEST_URI does not match. Is the flow of statements wrong?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (havij|libwwwperl|wget|python|nikto|curl|scan|java|winhttp|clshttp|loader) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wp-login.php|wp-admin/|wp-content/plugins/|wp-includes/).* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a `!` in front of your `%{REQUEST_URI}` regex. That means:

1. If user agent is `-`
2. **OR** if user agent is havij, wget, etc
3. **AND** if the request is **NOT** wp-login.php, wp-admin, etc.

You need to remove the negating match:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (havij|libwwwperl|wget|python|nikto|curl|scan|java|winhttp|clshttp|loader) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(wp-login.php|wp-admin/|wp-content/plugins/|wp-includes/).* [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]
```